# Calling an API from External environment

Tags: api

I'm working on an app in my company office environment. My server environment is such that I have two servers, Server A consist of all the data, and Server B consist of only the API parameters.

When calling from external environment, I will type something like "http://115.36.45.8:Portno/api/Data/GetData" to enter Server B on Google Chrome, so as retrieve the information i want. Whenever I test from external environment, I uses my own mobile data instead of the office internal data network.

When I type my internal Ip address to test, the API seems working okay. I type something like this
http://192.168.52.2:Portno/api/Data/GetData. The information that I would like to retrieve was beautifully presented to me in the Chrome.

However, when I type the external address,"http://115.36.45.8:Portno/api/Data/GetData", this doesn't happen. No data. Chrome reflects, Error diconnect.

I did the following troubleshooting:

a) I asked my vendor to check the port whether it is open. Vendor telnet and it sure was working. In fact if it doesn't work, I probably won't get any data retrieve from internet address (http://192.168.52.2:Portno/api/Data/GetData).

b) I use my mobile phone my laptop using external data, I asked different vendor to try access, all couldn't enter from external environment.

c) My infra team, also checked that there is no firewall or Antivirus that may have blocked the path since telnet works.

Anyone can advise what can I do to find out why external environment cannot access my api? Appreciate it.